# Intellij IDEA Community vs Educational

Tags: intellij-idea, ide

I am a student learning to code (I know much, but not very much).

I was installing the IntelliJ IDEA community version when I saw there was also an educational version. Both are free. Which one of the IDE should I choose?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA Educational = IntelliJ IDEA Community + [EduTools plug-in](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10081-edutools). You can install either one. They work the same.